# How to call a php static function and pass values to it

Tags: php

I know this might be a basic question but when I google it ,found different solutions for different php versions..in brief without wasting your time I have a.
class `

```
class UploadHandler
{
    protected $options; 
    public static $path;

public $prop1='';  
function __construct($options=null,$x){
$this->prop1  = $x;
    $this->options = array(
        'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).$this->getPath(),
        'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().$this->getPath(),` ....and so on
```

AND methods inside it:

```
public function getPath() 
    {

return self::$path;
}

static public function setPath($autoSave)
```

{

```
self::$path = $autoSave;
```

}

and in another place I do this:
`require('upload.class.php');`.......//the above class consists inside this

```
UploadHandler::setPath('/files/');
```

why doesn't it  work...??..please help me or guide me to a better tutorial

Comment: you dont construct a static class. so __construct will not be executed unless you do it manually include('ClassName.php'); ClassName::__contruct($options, $x);

Comment: But it gives me 
Fatal error: Call to undefined method UploadHandler::__contruct()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<?php

class UploadHandler {

    public static $path;

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function getPath() {
        return self::$path;
    }

    static public function setPath( $autoSave ) {
        self::$path = $autoSave;
    }
}

echo '1: ', UploadHandler::getPath(), '<br />';

UploadHandler::setPath('/files/');

echo '2: ', UploadHandler::getPath(), '<br />';

?>
```